# Atom.io: Change default syntax highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I want my Atom.io opens "template.cshtml" files as html files.
I installed package "file-types"
and add to my config.cson as:

But I see my templates.cshtml as early.

Please help me with config.cson

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [language-cshtml](https://atom.io/packages/language-cshtml), it's an atom package meant directly at `cshtml` files which adds **styntax highlighting**.

Comment: Glad to help my friend :)